# Programatically get users that have permissions on my YouTube channel

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Looking over all YouTube APIs, I didn't manage to find any API that allows me to check what are the users that have permissions on my channel (Manager/Editor/Viewer etc). I'm thinking I may be missing something. I have even looked on the Content ID API and found the contentOwners method, but I don't think it has anything to do with who has permissions on my channel.

Therefore, is there a way to list all of the users that have permissions on my channel programatically?